# How to convert SVG into Canvas without displaying the introduction of SVG?

Tags: javascript, svg

I use JS to introduce `SVG` as an external file and turn it into `canvas`. But there is a problem that the introduced `SVG` must be added to the page as a node, and it must be in a non-hidden state to take effect. However, I want to just display the canvas without `SVG` node, the whole code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>svgToCanvas</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="../img/ico/one.ico" />


<script src="../js/jquery/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/canvg/dist/browser/canvg.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function svgToCanvas()
    {
        var embedTag = document.createElement('embed');
        embedTag.type = "image/svg+xml";
        embedTag.src = "../img/svg/tiger.svg";
        embedTag.onload = function()
        {
            var svg1 = embedTag.getSVGDocument();
            var node1 = svg1.getElementById("tiger1");   // tiger1 is <svg>'s id value, <svg> is in file ../img/svg/tiger.svg.
            var node1Text = node1.outerHTML.trim();
            
            try
            {
                var svgWidth = node1.attributes.width.value;
                var svgHeight = node1.attributes.height.value;
                
                embedTag.width = svgWidth;
                embedTag.height = svgWidth;
                
                var canvas1 = document.getElementById("canvasId");
                canvas1.width = svgWidth;
                canvas1.height = svgWidth;
                
                canvg(canvas1, node1Text);
            }
            catch (error)
            {
                console.error('svg tag must add  width="841" height="800" or likeness, Otherwise, it gets null.');
            }
            
        };
        document.getElementById("dv").appendChild(embedTag);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button onclick="svgToCanvas();">button</button>

<hr />

<canvas id="canvasId" ></canvas>

<hr />

<div  style="" id="dv"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Thank you.

Comment: how about sticking the svg into a div with 0 height, overflow hidden? I think that still counts as visible, but won't show anything to the user...

Comment: Good direction of thinking and yahwoo~Successful ! `<div  style="width:0px;height:0px;overflow: hidden;" id="dv" ></div>` That's it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use an `<object>` tag instead of `<embed>`. Then you have access to the content document, provided the linked file fullfills the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).

```
    var embedTag = document.createElement('object');
    embedTag.type = "image/svg+xml";
    embedTag.data = "../img/svg/tiger.svg"; //sic
    embedTag.onload = function()
    {
        var svgDOM = embedTag.contentDocument;
        //...
    };
```

Alternatively, you can simply [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch) the file via XHR and parse it:

```
fetch("../img/svg/tiger.svg")
    .then(response => response.text)
    .then(str => {
        var svgDOM = new DOMParser()​​.parseFromString(str, "image/svg+xml");
        //....
    });
```

Comment: I haven't used `XMLHttpRequest` of `JS` so I don't really understand it, but I think it's the right way to think about this question, but I've solved it so far so I don't have to learn how to use `XMLHttpRequest` for a while, thank you.

Comment: <embed> (through its [`getSVGDocument()`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/iframe-embed-object.html#the-embed-element:dom-media-getsvgdocument) method) and <object> should both allow to access the content (though both might soon get deprecated so one should prefer <iframe> over these anyway). And <object> as the same limitations regarding the need to be *visible* in the doc. Only the DOMParser would work here.